# Pass pre populated values to SQL Server database table (using Blazor)

Tags: forms, asp.net-core, blazor

I'm trying to make a booking function, where there are a set of buttons to click depending on for how long you want to book a room; 15 min, 30 min, 60 min.

I need the function to send a set of data items (like `AppointmentStart`, `AppointmentEnd`, `RoomId` etc.) to the data table upon a button click. I've tried to figure hidden fields out but getting nowhere.

The code for one of the buttons (which isn't working because I can't choose what to populate the fields with as I can't have both the @bind and a value="x"):

```
@if (@schedule.AppointmentDateStart >= ChooseTimeSlot.AddMinutes(15))
{
    <div class="col">
        <EditForm class="" Model="@schedule" OnValidSubmit="@ValidSubmit">
            <button class="btn btn-primary form-control">15 min</button>
            <input type="hidden" @bind="@schedule.Room.Id" class="form-control" />
            <input type="hidden" @bind="@schedule.AppointmentHeading" class="form-control" />
            <input type="hidden" @bind="@schedule.AppointmentDateStart" class="form-control" />
            <input type="hidden" @bind="@schedule.AppointmentDateEnd" class="form-control" />
            <input type="hidden" @bind="@schedule.BookerId" class="form-control" />
        </EditForm>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Are you receiving an error when you test the code?  If so, can you please post the error message?

Comment: Blazor is C# code - you seem to already have the `schedule` object, so you don't need all those hidden inputs - all that is doing is adding hidden data to the page. You don't seem to need an EditForm either as you are not validating anything or asking them to "Edit" anything. You could just have a button that has an `@onclick` handler something like `@onclick=@( () => AppointmentChosen(15) )`  and all the rest of the data is already in `schedule`

Comment: Sorry, guess I was tired writing this. Yes, there are a few things alread set in the database for this UI-scenario(an ipad outside a meetingroom); Room.Id (pre chosen room), BookerID (anonumous due to fast booking). So the items I need to populate is `AppointmentDateStart = DateTime.Now()`, `AppointmentDateEnd = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes`(15/30/60 etc depending on pressed button). 
There will also be one other UI, where you as a user (or admin) can book a room through a login - where the user can add an AppointmentHeading, choose different days etc. And an Admin can edit appoints and users etc.

Comment: Thanks @MisterMagoo. I will try the changes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@onclick=@( () => AppointmentChosen(15) )
```

from @MistMagoo got me back on track, so this is the solution:

```
<div class="col"><button class="btn btn-primary form-control" @onclick=@(() => TimeSlot(15, TRoomId))>15 min</button></div>

@code{
[Parameter] public int TRoomId { get; set; }

newSchedule = new Schedule();
        {
        var SlotAdd = RoundUp(DateTime.Now, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(NextTimeSlot));

        newSchedule.RoomId = roomId;
        newSchedule.AppointmentHeading = "Snabb";
        newSchedule.AppointmentDateStart = DateTime.Now;
        newSchedule.AppointmentDateEnd = SlotAdd;
        newSchedule.BookerId = 1007;
        newSchedule.IsConfirmed = true;

    }
```

}